# How to Cover code written inside taskExecutor.execute(new Runnable..) using junit5

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit, junit5

Want to write junit5 test case/coverage for code inside execute method as below are my sample(dummy) src class, actual methods contains project lot of business logic.

[image]

If i mock the taskExecutor, it bypass whole execute() with dummy values.

Any suggestion how can i cover run method in attached code, Below are sample test case

[image]

Comment: Please [don't post images of code (or errors)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/6395627).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can outsource your in-lined `Runnable` to its own class like:

```
public class MyRunnable implements Runnable {

  private final JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

  public MyRunnable(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
    this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
  }

  @Override
  public void run() {
    // ... do your logic here
  }
}
```

and then write a unit test for this class to verify its behaviour in isolation.

Inside your `RedisScheduler` you can then make use of your new class:

```
taskExecutor.execute(new MyRunnable(jdbcTemplate));
```

Comment: solution looks good but code is in production so they won't allow me to change any source code, due to junit testcase. Is there anyway to achieve this without changing the source?